# ARKIT Changing node position according to physical object

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am trying to move a node relative to a face, so if the user face move right a diamond shape should move right exactly the same x. I have done it perfectly using **ARFaceTrackingConfiguration**. However, If there is a big distance between iPhone & the face the renderer delegate method does not fire anymore.

So I guess ARFaceTrackingConfiguration is not meant to be used on long distances because it uses depth sensors which apparently doesn't support that.

So my question is, does ARKit support adding nodes relative to an physical object and when this object moves, it would update me with the position of this object so that I can update the node?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have answered your own question.

Yes, with ARKit (and the scene graph / renderer APIs of your choice, such as SceneKit), you can place virtual content such that it moves with the tracked face. In `ARSCNView`, all you need to do is assign that content as a child of the node you get from `renderer(_:didAdd:for:)` — SceneKit automatically takes care of moving the node whenever ARKit reports that the face has moved.

If ARKit cannot track the face because it's outside the usable range of the TrueDepth camera… then it's not tracking the face. (Welcome to [tautology club](https://xkcd.com/703/).) That means it doesn't know where the face is, can't tell you how the face is moving, and thus can't automatically move virtual content to follow the face.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that if the true depth camera cant detect the face then renderer(_ renderer: didUpdate will not fire. However, my question is, can I lock the face and then track it. I mean if I tell the end user you need to get close first, can I put an anchor and then add an object relative to this anchor so that I wouldn't be dependent on the face detection?

Comment: Are you saying you want to place content relative to the face's last known position? (And by implication, have that content's position remain static until the face reappears?)